# Angular flow when creating nested directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Suppose I have `my-drtv1` directive which creates `my-drtv2` in its view which creates `my-drtv3` in its view and so on until `my-drtv5` .

In the controller of `my-drtv1` there is a `$http` calling which its callback throw an event which would be catch in listener in `my-drtv5`.

i.e

```
.directive('myDrtv1', function () {
    return {
        controller: function ($scope,$http) {
            $http.get(this.requestUrl,{params:params}).then(function() {
                $scope.$broadcast("Got it");
            })
        }
    }
})
.directive('myDrtv5', function () {
    return {
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.$on('Got it', fucntion () {
                ...
            })
        }
    }
})
```

Does I have a guarantee that always the callback `$http.then(...)` would be occur after the `$scope.$on('Got it', fucntion () {...})` has defined ?

Comment: You can use `$rootScope.$broadcast('Got it', function(){...})` to be sure that every listener in app will receive event.

Comment: This is not the point of my question , the point is on the $http response timing .

Answer (score 0):

To ensure drtv5 handle event you can notify drtv1 with the same mecanism :

```
.directive('myDrtv1', function () {
return {
    controller: function ($scope,$http) {
        $scope.$on('handled', fucntion () {
           $http.get(this.requestUrl,{params:params}).then(function() {
               $scope.$broadcast("Got it");
           })
        }
    }
}
})
.directive('myDrtv5', function () {
    return {
    controller: function ($scope) {
        $scope.$on('Got it', fucntion () {
            ...
        })
        $scope.emit('handled')
    }
  }
})
```

or if you don't use isolate scope call a method defined on drtv1 :

```
    .directive('myDrtv1', function () {
return {
    controller: function ($scope,$http) {
        $scope.ready = function() {
           $http.get(this.requestUrl,{params:params}).then(function() {
               $scope.$broadcast("Got it");
           })
        }
    }
}
})
.directive('myDrtv5', function () {
    return {
    controller: function ($scope) {
        $scope.$on('Got it', fucntion () {
            ...
        })
        $scope.ready();
    }
  }
})
```